# How to get the number of registrants (RNG module) from the theme layer

Tags: 8, rng

In my theme I want to display not only the maximum number of registrants on the full view of a node but also the number of seats still available.

What is the easiest way to get the number of registrants? In Drupal 7 I retrieved this number by passing the node id into the registration_event_count() function, does RNG provide a similar function?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the event manager service to grab an event meta object. The event meta object contains a bunch of helpers to manipulate registrations and registrants. In your template preprocess functions add whatever data you want from the event meta object.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_HOOK(&$variables) {
  $event_entity = $entity; // Provide your entity

  /** @var \Drupal\rng\EventManagerInterface $event_manager */
  $event_manager = \Drupal::service('rng.event_manager');
  $event_meta = $event_manager->getMeta($event_entity);
  $mydata = $event_meta->whatever(); 
   // See \Drupal\rng\EventMetaInterface for methods. e.g:
   // $event_meta->getRegistrants()
   // $event_meta->getRegistrations()
   // $event_meta->countRegistrations()
   // $event_meta->getCapacity()
   // $event_meta->remainingCapacity()
  $variables['myvariable'] = $mydata;
}
```

For nodes, replace `mymodule_preprocess_HOOK` with `mymodule_preprocess_node` and `$entity` with `$variables['node']`.

Comment: Thx! There were some errors coming from your code that I managed to fix after some experimentation, if you want you can update your answer and I can mark is as accepted. edit: putting it in answer due to lack of code support in comments

Comment: Its generalised to avoid hard-coding to nodes. RNG can support any entity, so the answer is generic. Added node example.

Comment: In a plain PHP function, `$this` doesn't have any particular meaning, as it's not code inside a class. `$this->eventManager->getMeta($event_entity)` should rather be `$event_manager->getMeta($event_entity)`.